# Select MapImageLayer along with FeatureLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I have FeatureLayer on top of MapImageLayer so both layers are intersecting each other on some points. I have to show popup on map click which will contains all features available on click point. It means popup will have multiple pages. Right now when I click on map I get only feature layer's value and popup also contains only feature layer's value. Please help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign a popup template to any sublayer you want to present information on their features. Take a look at this example I made for you,

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Hello World App</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      'esri/Map',
      'esri/views/MapView',
      'esri/layers/MapImageLayer'
    ], function(Map, MapView, MapImageLayer) {

      const renderer = {
        type: 'simple',
        symbol: {
          type: 'simple-fill',
          style: 'none',
          outline: {
            color: [0, 255, 0, 0.5],
            width: 0.75
          }
        }
      };

      const layer = new MapImageLayer({
        url:
          'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer',
        sublayers: [
          {
            id: 0,
            visible: true,
            title: 'Cities',
            popupTemplate: {
              title: '{areaname} City',
              content: '{pop2000} people lived in this city in 2000'
            }
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            visible: true,
            title: 'Highways',
            popupTemplate: {
              title: '{route} Route',
              content: [
                {
                  type: 'fields',
                  fieldInfos: [
                    {
                      fieldName: 'type',
                      label: 'Type'
                    },
                    {
                      fieldName: 'length',
                      label: 'Length'
                    },
                    {
                      fieldName: 'admn_class',
                      label: 'Adm. Class'
                    },
                    {
                      fieldName: 'toll_rd',
                      label: 'Toll?'
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            visible: true,
            title: 'States',
            popupTemplate: {
              title: '{state_name} State',
              content: '{pop2000} people lived in this state in 2000'
            }
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            visible: true,
            title: 'Counties',
            renderer,
            popupTemplate: {
              title: '{name} County',
              content: '{pop2000} people lived in this county in 2000'
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'dark-gray-vector',
        layers: [layer]
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: 'viewDiv',
        map: map,
        zoom: 3,
        center: [-99, 39]
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```